# How do you make lights affect 2D sprites in a 3D environment using Unity's URP render pipeline?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, lighting, shadows

I'm using Unity, URP and have 2d sprites characters in a 3D environment. I want 2D sprites to be affected by lights/shadows like the rest of the environment.

-I know if I use a 2D renderer I can use 2D lights but then I lose the projected shadows from both 3D objects and 2D Sprites. 
-If I use the standard render pipeline i can make it work but I don't want to miss on all the tools that URP brings to the table.

In summary, is it possible to use 2D lights or any light that affects 2D sprites in URP ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered drawing your sprites with a lit shader made for 3D, like one of the lit particle shaders?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, yes I tried every shader for URP and non of them seem to work, they either not render the sprite at all of remain the same.